# Is this sentence correct in grammar and does it even make sense

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, american-english, pronouns, sentence

This sentence:

> You have the right to ask for someone in the United States of America.

- Does it have any grammatical errors?
- Does it even make sense? I think it is usually ...to ask for someTHING ...not someONE

Comment: Yes you can ask for someone. If you provide more context it would help though...

Comment: Target red cards customer satisfaction. Talking to the customer service people

Comment: Question: "Who just came into the office?" Reply: "Some visitor - she's asking for Mr. Jones." Rude eavesdropping visitor: "Darned right I am. You have the right to ask for someone in the United States of America." (Yes, you have the right to ask for someone in English; it usually means you are requesting to see or speak with that person.)

Comment: This question might be a better fit for our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Please support it. Thanks!

Comment: You have the right to ask to speak with a person physically located in the USA, not (probably) India.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the sentence is grammatically correct. It is, however, ambiguous; it may mean *You have the right to ask to speak to someone who is in the USA* (as opposed, perhaps, to someone in a call centre), or it may mean *One of the freedoms this country guarantees is the right to ask to speak to somebody* (as in JRs comment: this is deliberately rude).  And you are right that it is usually *to ask for something* rather than *someone*, but that has very little to do with good English.

Comment: Or maybe you only have a right to ask a question on behalf of a citizen of the USA. (I asked the professor the question for Jane).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is grammatically correct, and given your comment concerning the context, it now makes sense.

What it means is that you have the right to request a customer service representative who is from the United States, as opposed to someone from India or another country where the accent may be nearly impossible for an American to understand.